# Is this the typical approach to modern OpenGL UI & Text rendering, for mobile?

Tags: opengl, performance, opengl-es, mobile, efficiency

I'm implementing GUI in OpenGL ES 2.0 to fit with my application framework's existing structure. I'd like to have the UI rendering eat as little mobile processing capacity as possible. So to confirm...

**Is the following *general* approach standard these days**, for **mobile games?**

Use the following for each of **controls** and **text**:

- One VBO - one `glDrawElements()` call for all elements
- One texture atlas (certainly just one for text, preferably just one for control backgrounds)
- Many quads batched in VBO, each quad corner having appropriate UVs to access the character or detail texture in question
- For overlapping UI "panels", turn on depth buffer & use different float depths per panel
- Modifiable textfields have their own small, separate VBO modified using `glBufferSubData()` or `glBufferData()` (to shorten on backspace/delete) as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821969/what-is-the-proper-way-to-modify-opengl-vertex-buffer).

Please confirm / deny / correct existing points or add missing details where necessary.

Comment: Is this speculative? My impression is that there are certain standard ways of doing things that crystallise in our industry, and that this is one such thing - when there are solid reasons to do a certain thing a certain way, say 80% of the time, I guess one can assume a _de facto_ standard.

Comment: I wouldn't separate text fields in terms of rendering. By simply batching all the vertex data you can together, they should be taken care of automatically.

Comment: @snake5 Fair enough. I assumed that it would be cheaper to reupload a small buffer using glBufferData, than having to recompact / reupload the whole thing if some characters were deleted, hence the thought to keep dynamic textfields separate - but maybe it really doesn't matter. Also re separating text from the rest, that's so I can use a different shader (e.g. SDF or outline) for text as opposed to plain diffuse shaders for the control graphics. Then again the question is about general methods, not my specific needs.

Comment: glBufferData has been extremely slow regardless of the situation in my experience. IMO, the best way to avoid it to just use one big buffer for everything. You can still flush submitted vertices whenever you change shaders/textures, that works with either method.

Comment: I would say the 80% of games don't bother with it at all - they just take what their engine offers. As for what I did, I transform all UI data on CPU(for easier hit testing) and stream them using buffer orphaning. What is really the standard only huge poll would find....

Comment: @wondra Respectfully, I disagree. If you're not heavily into writing engines, you wouldn't really know typical methods. There are indeed standards in regards to these sorts of matters. I've read up quite a lot on text rendering for example and some approaches are far more common (e.g. SDF) in games than others (e.g. polygonised text). I'm confident of a worthwhile answer from users here. I'll look up buffer orphaning - thanks.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer you are trying to judge the industry by hobby-dev and scholarly articles. Even though I don't know what the practice is, I advice you - don't try to fool yourself into trusting questionable sources. *Who* could answer your question correctly? Only very experienced professional engine developer with a lot of technically-educated friends in half of other companies. I find hard to believe that people answering this are such type of people. Btw, both SDF and polygonised text have serious flaws making them hard(if not impossible) to be widely used professionally.

Comment: @wondra You're stretching a bit too much now. Also... are you one such individual? Is that where the judgement of "hobby developers" on this site comes from? We can google a lot - between that and interacting on sites like this, we can get relatively solid ideas of what the standards are. I think let's leave it there before the comments get cluttered further.

Comment: @wondra There was no need to get an unpleasant attitude - as I said, I _respectfully_ disagree with you, and in truth, no one in life has any obligation to agree with anyone else. If you want to try to use my rep against me, well - you woudn't be the first. Can't win everyone over! Good luck in your quest for knowledge here.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer sorry, I did not meant to be rude. Voting to close this anyway though.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any mention of alpha blending (with back to front rendering).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your points seem reasonable.

For static elements that are set up once and never change, you can certainly pack them into a `GL_STATIC_DRAW` buffer and keep it alive for as long as needed. If you still have to move these static elements around in the screen, then this approach is not very interesting anymore because each would need a transformation matrix that can only be set via uniforms, so it results in one draw call per element.

The "usual" way of handling UI is to just resubmit the whole vertex data each frame, using screen space positions. Generate the final 2D vertexes in the application code and submit to a dynamic VBO. So you can, as described in your first point, draw everything with a single draw call (assuming other things like textures are not involved. Texture altas can help).

So the decision might be between either several draw calls per frame or one large buffer update per frame and a handful of draws.

You should certainly try to batch things that share the save properties together. Drawing with depth enabled is also interesting, since it should lift the requirement of a sorting step before submission.

You can also try to be smart and avoid resubmitting individual UI elements that didn't change or move in a given frame (assuming you are taking the path of generating the final vertex position on the CPU-side).

Since this is about mobile, mandatory read: [Best Practices for Working with Vertex Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wasn't sure about the depth buffer because I assume anyway that it costs GPU time when the depth buffer is turned on; but OTOH if I don't use it, a CPU sorting step is required as you suggest - in fact I think I prefer CPU-side sort and just modify the vertices' z values per quad. About resubmission, I guess just `glBufferSubData()` at best, `glBufferData()` at worst? No other tricks? - don't want to  resubmit unchanged elements. TY for that article - I found it yet again today and interleaving attributes is another thing I took from there to include in the UI work.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer Actually, `glBufferData` might be more efficient due to something called "buffer orphaning" ([more info here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Buffer_update)). In a nutshell, it might avoid expensive CPU-GPU synchronization if you just allocate a new buffer, instead of updating an existing. As always, benchmark before making a final choice. As for the depth buffer, I'd give it a try anyways. Depth testing is "free" in any modern renderer, so my guess is that it should be faster than manual sorting... but again, benchmark it first ;)

Comment: Thanks - I was just looking up buffer orphaning concept now in fact - hugely beneficial to understand why to generally prefer `glBufferData`. FYI I'll leave the question a while still to brew / get more answers but yours and snake5's comments have given good direction.

Comment: He who dares, succeeds. All the others lose out. Thanks glampert for making the attempt.